# Mongomapper - embedded document or one-to-many or ...?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

There is an user model and an account model. An user can have many accounts. Approximately an user has 5 accounts.

What kind of associations should I use in this case: EmbeddedDocument or one-to-many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could an account exist without a user? Could you have more than 1 user with the same account?
It seems it doesn't so perhaps it is betther to embed the accounts into the User.

[Review the Mongo documentation about embedding vs linking](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Schema+Design#SchemaDesign-EmbeddingandLinking)

Comment: An account couldn't exist without a user, but 1 user can have different accounts. And one account can belong to different users. Does it seem to be many-to-many relationship, doesn't it?

Comment: Then it seems to be a Many to many relationship, which are generally done by linking.

Comment: try using a third collection which contains the id of the user and the account. Perhaps called UserAccountRelationship. If you are not bounded to a document oriented database such as MongoDB, A Relational DB seems more suited for this usecase